# MYSQL WHERE clause not working for generated field

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause

Hi guys for some reason the WHERE rating = 1 clause is not working in this case. I think it might be to do with the outer sql statement being constructed prior to the inner statement being executed for the as rating generated field, as it works fine with the other fields.

```
SELECT 
    property.id as propertyid, 
    property.main_image as mainimageid, 
    property.number as number, 
    property.address as address, 
    property.number as number, 
    property.area as area, 
    image.id as imageid, 
    CAST((SELECT sum(review.rating) / COUNT(*) / 20 as innerrating 
          FROM 
              review 
          WHERE 
              review.propertyid = property.id) AS decimal(3,2)) as rating
    FROM 
        property 
    LEFT JOIN 
        propertyimage ON propertyimage.propertyid = property.id 
    LEFT JOIN 
        image on image.id = propertyimage.imageid 
    LEFT JOIN 
        review on review.propertyid = property.id 
    WHERE 
        rating = 1 
    GROUP BY propertyid
```

any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: `decimal(3,2)`? if that inner select returns 1.5, then yeah, your `where` won't match at all.

Comment: Switch your WHERE for HAVING

Comment: I see the problem now thanks Marc,  is there a way to focus on the result of the outer query constructed field? or am I stuck with only the inner query value

Comment: You should use rating > 1